# Can't locate image on python

Tags: python, pyautogui

I try to locate an image on my screen. But it always shows this -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MerazulIslam/Desktop/ZOOM_BOT/bot.py", line 20, in <module>
    find_btn = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'C:\Users\MerazulIslam\Desktop\ZOOM_BOT\Capture.PNG', confidene=0.5)
  File "C:\Users\MerazulIslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 175, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MerazulIslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 213, in locateOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MerazulIslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 359, in locateOnScreen
    screenshotIm = screenshot(region=None) # the locateAll() function must handle cropping to return accurate coordinates, so don't pass a region here.
  File "C:\Users\MerazulIslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 134, in wrapper
    raise PyScreezeException('The Pillow package is required to use this function.')
pyscreeze.PyScreezeException: The Pillow package is required to use this function.
```

my code-

```
import pyautogui

find_btn = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'C:\Users\MerazulIslam\Desktop\bot\Capture.PNG')
print(find_btn)
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you installed Pillow?

    pip install Pillow

Comment: do pip install pillow first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just try to reinstall `pyautogui` with all dependencies to make sure nothing missing:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyautogui
```

Comment: Despite being listed as a requirement in the README for PyAutoGUI, Pillow isn't listed as a requirement in `setup.py` so I don't think this will solve the problem on this occasion.

Comment: @JosephRedfern pillow is a dependency for `pyscreeze` which is a dependency for `pyautogui` so basically it's got resintalled. There're couple other similar indirect dependencies which are not in the `setup.py`, so it's better to reinstall everything at once, not individually.

Comment: You're quite right, apologies. I'd assumed `Pillow` would be a direct dependency of `PyAutoGUI` but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you need the Pillow package to be installed in order to use locateOnScreen.

You can install it with `pip install Pillow`.